# MySQL query for add join after check column

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have created database with following tables.

```
booking (id, user_id, user_table, date);
user (id, fname, lname);
tmp_user (id, fname, lname);
```

The `user_id` of booking table refer both `user` table id and `tmp_user` table id. I use `user_table` column for keep user table type.

I want to write a query to get booking details with user details. So i should check `user_table` column value before join user table.

Is it possible? How can i do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Still i have no idea to do that. :(

Comment: so based on user_table column you will know if the join will be to user or tmp_user right? i do not see why you should check user_table column i.e. try select [cols] from booking b inner join user u on u.id = b.user_id.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a query of this type by joining both in and then using precedence:

```
select b.*,
       (case when u.id is not null then u.fname else tu.fname end) as fname,
       (case when u.id is not null then u.lname else tu.lname end) as lname
from booking b left outer join
     user u
     on b.user_id = u.id left outer join
     tmp_user tu
     on b.user_id = tu.id
```

You can also add in the condition `and u.uid is null` to the second join.  I don't know if that would help or hinder performance.

Oh, if you want the user table value, then that is just a small modification to the logic:

```
select b.*,
       (case when b.user_table = 'user' then u.fname else tu.fname end) as fname,
       (case when b.user_table = 'tmp_user' then u.lname else tu.lname end) as lname
from booking b left outer join
     user u
     on b.user_id = u.id left outer join
     tmp_user tu
     on b.user_id = tu.id;
```

Comment: This query is not working for my task. I want to check user_table value.